# Laravel database builder substrings

Tags: laravel

In my database i have field ('content') which one contains strings. My server should gets only 100 first chars from those strings (can be less but not more) how can i achieve that? I have tried `'SUBSTRING(content, 1, 100)'`

using method above laravel gives error : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUBSTRING(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the selectRaw method like this:

```
$orders = DB::table('tableName') ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING( ... ), ...)->get();
```

For more info check the docs here.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can also take it out and intercept it.

```
$content = DB::table('tableName')->limit(1)->value('content');
echo substr($content, 0, 100);
```

Comment: Imagine when i need to get milion records from DB and any of them contains field(content) with 1.000.000 chars it will be inefficiency, so i predicted that and i would to DB returns shortened strings.